# lateinit property binding has not been initialized though i did not set it as lateinit

Tags: kotlin, android-viewbinding

I faced that error when i was trying to update my views with new ViewBinding stuff. I don't define the value as "lateinit" but logccat says "lateinit property binding has not been initialized" why i m taking this ?

Thanks in advance.

The exception is on private val email and password rows.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private val email    = binding.emailText.text.toString()  
private val password = binding.passwordText.text.toString()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val guncelKullanici = auth.currentUser

   if (guncelKullanici!= null) {
       val intent = Intent(this, haber_akisi::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
       finish()




   }
}

fun girisYap ( view: View) {

    if (email.isNotBlank()  && password.isNotBlank()) {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val intent = Intent(this,haber_akisi::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()

            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }}else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen E-mail ve Password alanlarını doldurunuz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

fun kayitOl ( view : View) {

    if ( email.isNotBlank() && password.isNotBlank() ) {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(this, haber_akisi::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen E-mail ve Password alanlarını doldurunuz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I don't define the value as "lateinit" ` Are you sure? Because this part of the code you posted says otherwise `private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`. I would rename the title tbh.

Comment: I was speaking about email value and i declared it

Comment: you do mention email and password, but the error is this "lateinit property binding has not been initialized", and I'll be honest, I think that the compiler knows better what the issue is. That error mentions `binding` which is a value that is declared as `lateinit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `private val email    = binding.emailText.text.toString()`  is using the "binding" variable before it has been initialized. The error is saying that the "lateinit var binding" has not been initialized yet but you are accessing it on `private val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()`

Edit: One way to solve this is to make email and password as lateinit vars too. Another way is to not have an email and password class level properties and just access the binding where it's needed like in girisYap() and kayitOl()

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing binding(ActivityMainBinding Identifier) in the next lines, after its declaration.

You need to initialize binding before using it.